# Having trouble with PHP classes and MySQL insertion/updating

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some trouble updating a MySQL database via a PHP class (this is my first real foray into PHP classes, so I might be missing some very basic elements).  I've included the code that is relevant to the problems I am having (that is, not properly updating the MySQL table).

To quickly explain my code, I pull a user's information from the database when an object is constructed.  Then, I call the function `modify_column()` to increase or decrease a numeric value from the data I've pulled.  Finally, I run `save()` to update the MySQL table.

I am having two problems: (1) `$this->info` is not being updated properly by the modify function (for example, if I `modify_column('age', '1')`, a var_dump shows `age int(3)` rather than `age string(2) = 10` (assuming the original age was 9). And (2), the update query is not working.  I'm assuming it's because I have an improperly-sized variable stemming from the first issue.

A snippet of the code (my database functions are based on a PDO wrapper and they have always worked just fine):

```
class user {

    public $id;

    public function __construct($id) {

        global $db;

        /* pull the user's information from the database */
        $bind = array(':id' => $id);
        $result = $db->select('user', 'id = :id', $bind, '*', SQL_SINGLE_ROW);

        $this->id = $result['id'];
        $this->info = $result;
    }

    /*
     * Update the user's MySQL table, thereby saving the data.
     */
    public function save() {

        global $db;

        $bind = array($this->id);
        $db->update('users', $this->info, 'id = ?', $bind);

    }

    public function modify_column($column, $amount) {
        $this->info[$column] += $amount;
    }
}
```

Also, please let me know if there is a neater way to do what I am trying to accomplish (that is, quickly modify numeric values in a table using class functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not have any provision for typing of your variables.  When you add your data to `$this->info` all the value are going to be set as strings.  You don't want to do incremental math (i.e. `+=`, `-=` etc.) on strings.  You need to cast to these values as integer.  What I suggest would be to add a class property having an array of your class properties and their types.  You will then be able to cast all you values according to their types when setting the `$info` array.

So something like this

```
protected $fields = array(
    'age' => 'integer',
    'name' => 'string',
    // etc.
}
```

Then you can add a function like this

```
protected function type_cast(&$value, $key) {
    // field type to use
    $type = $this->fields[$key];
    if ($type === 'integer') {
        $value = (integer)$value;
    } else if ($type === 'string') {
        $value =  (string)$value;
    } // etc.
}
```

And in your constructor, just walk `$result` through the `type_cast` function:

```
array_walk(&$result, array($this, 'type_cast'));
$this->info = $result;
```

You probably also need to make sure your id value cast as an integer if you are using an integer in the DB.

I am not sure how you DB abstraction works, so hard to tell what is happening. I would suggest echoing out the query itself and trying it against the database, or taking a look at the MySQL errors that are being returned to get a feel fro what is going wrong there.